# Bootstrap 3: Multi-tier navigation menu support for mobiles and up

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I understand that since that since the release of Bootstrap 3, multi-level/multi-tier navigation is no-longer officially supported out of the box. I don't understand why they have made this decision as it seems like a pretty stupid move to me but currently I am trying to restore this functionality/behaviour within my site.

Here is the html for my bootstrap navigation menu:

```
<nav id="topNavigation" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    
    <!-- Brand and toggle grouped for better mobile display-->
    
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand visible-xs" href="#">Menu</a> 
    </div>

    <!-- Content that requires toggling on mobile devices-->

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav level2">
        <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></li>
        <li>
          <a class="hidden-xs" href="/destinations/">Destinations</a>
          <a class="visible-xs dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Destinations <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu level3">
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a class="hidden-xs" href="/destinations/europe-the-caucasus/">Europe &amp; the Caucasus </a>
              <a class="visible-xs dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdownTwo">Europe &amp; the Caucasus  <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu level4">
                <li><a href="/destinations/europe-the-caucasus/albania/">Albania</a></li>
                <li><a href="/destinations/europe-the-caucasus/armenia/">Armenia</a></li>
                <li><a href="/destinations/europe-the-caucasus/azerbaijan/">Azerbaijan</a></li>
                <li><a href="/destinations/europe-the-caucasus/georgia/">Georgia</a></li>
                <li><a href="/destinations/europe-the-caucasus/europes-arctic-circle/">Europe&#39;s Arctic Circle</a></li>
                <li><a href="/destinations/europe-the-caucasus/romania/">Romania</a></li>
                <li><a href="/destinations/europe-the-caucasus/turkey/">Turkey</a></li>
                <li><a href="/destinations/europe-the-caucasus/montenegro/">Montenegro</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a class="hidden-xs" href="/destinations/north-africa/">North Africa</a>
              <a class="visible-xs dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdownTwo">North Africa <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu level4">
                <li><a href="/destinations/north-africa/egypt/">Egypt</a></li>
                <li><a href="/destinations/north-africa/libya/">Libya</a></li>
                <li><a href="/destinations/north-africa/morocco/">Morocco</a></li>
                <li><a href="/destinations/north-africa/mali-burkina-faso/">Mali &amp; Burkina Faso</a></li>
                <li><a href="/destinations/north-africa/sudan/">Sudan</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Currently, I have managed to restore the multi-level navigation functionality for the desktop using hover effects in pure css:

```
@media (min-width: 992px){

  /*Add multi-level navigation support*/
  .dropdown-submenu{position:relative;}
  .dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu{top:-2%;left:99.5%;-webkit-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;-moz-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;margin:0;padding:0}
  .dropdown-submenu:active>.dropdown-menu, .dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {display: block;}
  .dropdown-submenu>a:after{display:block;content:" ";float:right;width:0;height:0;border-color:transparent;border-style:solid;border-width:5px 0 5px 5px;border-left-color:#cccccc;margin-top:5px;margin-right:-10px;}
  .dropdown-submenu:active>a:after{border-left-color:#ffffff;}
  .dropdown-submenu.pull-left{float:none;}.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu{left:-100%;margin-left:10px;-webkit-border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;-moz-border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;}

  .navbar-nav > li:hover > ul.dropdown-menu,
  .navbar-nav > li:hover > ul.dropdown-menu > li.dropdown-submenu:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    background-color: #FFA050;
  }

  .navbar-nav > li:hover ul li a:hover,
  #topNavigation .navbar-nav > li.active ul li a:hover{
    background-color: #451F00;
    color: #FFA050; 
  }

  #topNavigation .navbar-nav > li.active ul li a {
    background-color: #FFA050;
    color: #451F00;
  }

}
```

This gives the following effect:

[image: Navigation Menu]

However, on mobile devices there seems to be a bit of an issue which I believe is caused by the data-toggle attributes.

[image: Mobile Navigation Menu]

The menu looks correct as you can see above however, when I click on one of the continents which should trigger the collapsed list of countries to open, it instead collapses the destinations dropdown wihtout displaying any the next tier of navigation.

My main question is, how can I adapt my code to ensure that the data-toggle attribute is targeting the correct menu exposing the content underneath? I've tried replacing the value in the data-toggle but this doesn't actually seem to be doing anything and exhibits the same behaviour no matter what is put here.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I'll also put together a fiddle to try and demonstrate the issue more clearly.

N.B. I've also tried following the tips in the link below but unforunately they don't seem to change the behaviour for mobile-sized screens at all:

http://www.jeffmould.com/2014/01/09/responsive-multi-level-bootstrap-menu/

Comment: to get this behaviour in mobile devices, you would need to get help of jquery to get tap or click event.

Comment: I know that. That's the easy part.

Comment: If you supply a http://jsfiddle.net/ I can help you out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the bootstrap dropdown source, it seems that boostrap attaches an event that triggers the a function that hides all dropdown-menu, when a dropdown item is clicked. If we stop that event from running and toggle the visibility ourselves when clicking a dropdown toggle, it should work. So something like:

```
//might be selecting too many things
$(".level3 .dropdown-toggle").click(function(e){
  $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('open') //show dropdown
  e.stopPropagation(); //stops from hiding menu
})
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mfirdaus/chJC4/)

I haven't tested how this code affects anything else, but I suppose it's a good start.

Comment: Nice work. Thanks for this. In the end our client decided to reduce the level of nesting on the site but this is still a huge help for future projects.

Comment: @mfirdaus Very nice job. That one saved me alot of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You have `data-toggle` set as "dropdownTwo" here.

```
<a class="visible-xs dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdownTwo">North Africa <b class="caret"></b></a>
```

In the [Bootstrap JS docs it is stated](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns) that:

```
data-toggle="dropdown" still required
Regardless of whether you call your dropdown via JavaScript or instead use the data-api, data-toggle="dropdown" is always required to be present on the dropdown's trigger element.
```

As your toggle isn't "dropdown" but "dropdownTwo", Bootstrap doesn't know what to target.

Comment: This has nothing to do with it. I've tried it with just dropdown and the dropdownTwo was an attempt to get it to work.